# From f[g[x,t]] to f[g]

Tags: differential-equations, functions, variable

How can you change

```
f[g[x,t],t]
```

to

```
f[g,t]
```

?

I have differential equations

```
Derivative[1,0][f][g[x,t],t]== f[g[x,t],t]*t+Derivative[2,0]f[g[x,t],t]
```

And

```
f'[g[x,t]]== f[g[x,t]]*t+f''[g[x,t]]
```

And I'd like to use DSolve with $g$ as an independant variable, meaning :

```
DSolve[Derivative[1,0][f][g,t]== f[g,t]*t+Derivative[2,0]f[g,t],f,{g,t}]
```

I tried :

```
(f'[g[x,t]]== f[g[x,t]]*t+f''[g[x,t]])/.g[x,t]-> g
```

but it failed

Comment: If you are only dealing with a single example with the same variables, the easiest way is to just use Find and Replace.

Answer (score 6):

```
f[g[x,t],t] /. g[___]->g
(*    f[g, t]    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

put bracket around f in the Derivative-commands `f -> [f]`:

```
Derivative[1, 0][f][g[x, t], t] ==f[g[x, t], t]*t + Derivative[2, 0][f][g[x, t], t]
(*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(f\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[g, t] == t f[g, t] + \!(\*SuperscriptBox[\(f\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[g, t]*)
```